# SQL query one-to-many

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I need SQL query for the below scenario.

2 tables: price & product

price table has ManyToOne relationship with product(i.e., many prices were applicable to one product).

Now I need a query to get only the product details which available in price table.

Note: Using hibernate, I have specified in price as

> @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
>   private Product product;

But I don't specify OneToMany in product.

Comment: I know that it is not an answer to your question, but why you decided to do it like this? From logic point of view, price is attribute of a product, so logically it should be a field on `Product` class. If you are willing to keep track of product's price in several shops (for example) you should keep it in `Map` on some 'Store' class. These are just good manners for anyone who is going to maintain your code.

Comment: As of now, price holds product_id. But product won't have any relation with price.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can return the product attribute in your query, example:

```
select p.product from price p where p = :price
```

Hope this can help. :)